# Angular SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get item details from my API and trying to show it in my Angular application. But when i get the data i have that error on my data object

message: "Unexpected end of input"

stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input↵    at FlorsComponent.push../src/app/manager/flors/flors.component.ts.FlorsComponent.editZone (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1703:14)↵    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///AppModule/FlorsComponent.ngfactory.js:20:27)↵    at handleEvent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:43342:41)↵    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44435:25)↵    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44138:12)↵    at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:40801:25)↵    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:41245:38↵    at HTMLButtonElement. (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59000:36)↵    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:31)↵    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36899:33)"

Result that return from API

```
{
"cubeAreaID":1019,
"repoID":16,
"cubeAreaName":"hkjh",
"createdBy":14,
"updatedBy":null,
"createdDate":"2019-01-09T22:12:37.5991778",
"updatedDate":null,"isActive":1
}
```

flor.ts

```
export interface Flor {
cubeAreaID: number;
repoID: number;
cubeAreaName: string;
createdBy: number;
updatedBy: number;
createdDate: string;
updatedDate: string;
isActive: number;
}
```

Service.ts

```
getFlorById(zoneID): Observable<Flor> {
return this.http.get<Flor>(this.baseUrl + 'CubeArea/GetCubeAreaById/?CubeAreaId=' + zoneID);
```

}

flor.component.ts

```
editZone(cubeAreaID) {

this.florService.getFlorById(cubeAreaID).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.flor = data;
  },
  error => {
    this.alertify.error(error);
  }
);

}
```

In flor.component.ts in data=> object is showing "Unexpected end of input" error. It s not returning erorr!. I just can see it when i debug. That code even not enter error => part. It s getting cubeAreaID correctly, trying to get data and that that go out from block.

PS : When this code make request api run correctly and return response correctly as wrote on the top.

I checked other question but coulndt find an answer for my problem. Generally they talk about json syntax error but i coulndt see anything wrong

Comment: What's your Http Content-Type

Comment: @phucnh Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8